# How many rectangles in a dodecagon?

Tags: geometry

How many rectangles are in a dodecagon?

I am unsure how to approach this. I've counted 12 so far but none more

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it depends on the dodecagon. If we assume that the vertices of the rectangle should also be vertices of the dodecagon, the answer may be none. It sounds like you have left out some key assumptions. Brevity is not necessarily a virtue here.

Comment: This may be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681565/how-many-rectangles-can-be-obtained-by-joining-four-of-the-12-vertices-of-a-1

Comment: Is it regular, the dodecagon?

Comment: If it is a regular dodecagon there will be 16 rectangles present in that dodecagon